# Replace english characters to malayalam characters in excel

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I want to replace English characters to Malayalam language characters as given criterio in excel

```
a=എ
b=ബി
C=സി
D=ഡി
E=ഇ
F=എഫ്
G=ജി
H=എച്ച്
I=ഐ
J=ജെ
K=കെ
L=എല്‍
N=എന്‍
M=എം
O=ഒ
P=പി
Q=ക്യു
R=ആര്‍
S=എസ്
T=ടി
U=യു
V=വി
W=ഡബ്ല്യു
X=എക്സ്
Y=വൈ
Z=ഇസെഡ്
```

For eg in column A "ABC" in Column B it has to appear as "എബിസി"

Comment: I think [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/excel/) might help you

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: I tried MS Excel translation option. But it didn't work for me as I thought. When we enter any characters in column A1 we wish to get its transliteration in column B1. For each letter's  transliteration letters are given in the above question.

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***If you have O365***

Set up a table with your equivalences *(I NAME'd it `tblLng`)*

[image]

Then, you can use this formula in B1:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",,VLOOKUP(MID(A1, SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),tblLng,2,FALSE))
```

[image]

If you do not have the `SEQUENCE` function I can provide a substitute.

If you do not have the `TEXTJOIN` function, look into using helper columns and or VBA.

***Edit***
As now noted in the comments, the OP wants to replace also digits, and wild card characters.

- Digits must be entered as **text** and not numbers, by either pre-pending the digit with a single quote; or pre-formatting the column as text.
- wild card characters (asterisk, tilde, question mark), must be prepended with a tilde in order to search for the actual character.

The formula can be changed for wild-card characters:

- `MID` portion:

  ```
    =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1, SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),"~","~~"),"?","~?"),"*","~*")`
  ```

-entire formula:

```
    =TEXTJOIN("",,VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1, SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),"~","~~"),"?","~?"),"*","~*"),tblLng,2,FALSE))
```

Comment: In Office 365 it works for me. Thank you. Is there any solution to get numbers as well ? For eg: input : ABC123  output എബിസി123

Comment: @AkbaraliCharankav Just extend your table.

Comment: Rosenfed, extended the table with numbers and special characters. Unfortunately it doesnt work for me. For eg: When I enter "ABC1" in B1 column it shows as " #N/A"

Comment: @AkbaraliCharankav You probably extended the table with numbers as *numbers*.  `VLOOKUP` sees "numbers" and "numbers stored as text" differently.  Either prepend the number with a single quote mark; or, ***before*** you enter the number into the cell, format it as Text.

Comment: .Thanks for the information. But When I typed " * " which gives output as "എ". How can I include the symbol " * " (star)

Comment: @AkbaraliCharankav Now you are adding wild card characters to the mix. As per MS documentation, you need to prepend wild card characters with a tilde in order to use the actual character.  In the above, you would need to change the `MID` function to `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1, SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),"~","~~"),"?","~?"),"*","~*")`

Answer (score 0):

It might not be elegant, but you can add something like this in B1 cell.

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"A";"എ");"B";"ബി")

It reacts like the REPLACE function but will replace any instance of A or B in this case.
You can extent the function nesting more substitute calls.